# What is average tree size?

Tags: random-forest, random-generation, mean

Suppose that you generate a sequence which stops with prob q at every step or proceeds with prob p. That is you will get bernulli sequence 0 or 10 or 110 or 11...10 with corresponding lengths 1, 2, 3, ... and probabilities $q$, $pq$, $p^2q$, ...

This is a [geometric series](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/76) with average length of $E[len] = 1*q + 2*pq + 3p^2q + \cdots = 1/q$. That is, if prob of failure is 1/5 then we normally will generate 5-digit lists with 5 trials.

Let the randomly generated list be

[image]

Now, suppose that 1-labeled nodes, which are considered "real" or "non-terminal", will also have children subtree. That is, once you have generated a list with method above, you generate another list below every 1-node. An example tree generated after the root node above would be (yes, we consider that 3-element list above as a "root")

[image]

You see that, in addition to having potentially long nodes, the trees may descend inifnitely downwards. How many trials do we need to generate such a tree?

[My simulation](http://scastie.org/12857) experiment demonstrates that the tree blows up at $p \geq 1/2$. That is, random tree generator never ends at such prob of spawning a node. I am curious to know the analytic solution, dependence of avg tree size on p.

Comment: Some essential information seems to be missing.  Exactly what "sequence" are you referring to?  The stopping probabilities?  How does such a sequence "represent a node" of a tree? How many nodes will be generated at each step and with what probabilities? What is the definition of "size"--number of nodes, number of children, depth, number of leaves, ...?

Comment: @whuber Thanks. This motivated me to explain clearly with illustration.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up.  Here is a simulation in `R` that--if you analyze it--will give you the answer. `tree <- function(p) {if (runif(1) < p) c(tree(p), tree(p), 1) else 0}`. (The output is a postfix representation of the tree.) You can study it by repeating the simulation, as in `p <- 0.4;
x <- replicate(1e4, length(tree(p)));
(c(Expectation=1/(1-2*p), Mean=mean(x), Std.Err=sd(x) / sqrt(length(x))))`

Comment: "How many trials do we need to generate such a tree?" The literal answer is "one".  Presumably, you intend some other meaning. If so, you should be explicit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each node in your tree you have one child with probability $p$ and 0 with probability $q = 1-p$.  Let $X$ be the random variable denoting the number of nodes (including leaves) in your tree.

If the first node has no children then the tree has one node.  If it has two children then the two subtrees are independent and have the same distribution as the original tree. Therefore, conditioned on the first node having two children, the expected number of nodes in the tree is $1 + 2 \mathbb E(X)$ (one original node plus the two subtrees).

Therefore we may write

$$\mathbb E(X) = q + p(1+2\mathbb E(X))$$
which we may rearrange to get
$$\mathbb E(X) = \frac 1{1 - 2p}$$

as long as $2p < 1$.  If $2p \geq 1$ there are no positive real solutions and the tree has infinite expected value.

Comment: It is interesting that you seem have intuitively proven that q$\sum_0^\infty (n+2)p^n = 1 + q\sum_0^\infty (n+1)p^n$, which can be done starting with $1 = q/q = q/(1-p) = q (1+p+p^2 + \cdots) = q((2-1) + (3-2)p + (4-3)p^2+\cdots) = q(2 + 3p + 4p^2 + \cdots) - q(1+ 2p + +3p^2+\cdots)$ in the list case. What is more interesting is your idea that $E = 1 + pE$ does agree with your $E = q + p(1+E)$ because $p+q = 1$ and we get $E = q + p + pE = 1 + pE$. It is like you assume  $E = 1 + pE$, plug it into $E = q + pE$ to get $E = q + p(1+E)$ and get it back, after simplifying the latter ;). Amazing

Answer (score 1):

A related problem is finding the average depth of such a tree.

Note that if you clip all the leaf nodes in your tree (of which there are n = E(X) = 1/(1-2p) on average), you will get an ordinary binary tree of size n/2 (with 0 1 or 2 children for each node instead of 0 or 2.)

The number of such trees is the Catalan number C((n-1)/2), and the expected depth of the tree grows as ~sqrt(n/2) = O(sqrt(1-2p)). (Trees of other depth have exponentially decaying probability, so it is safe to expect tree size roughly equal to the expected tree size.)